# AWS ECR tag mutability vs Lifecycle policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, lifecycle, amazon-ecr

Question is how ECR counts images with the same tag. For example if I push 1 time tag 'base-old' then 10 times image with the tag 'base' tag and I have a lifecycle rule that keeps up to 10 images with prefix 'base' should it delete 'base-old' or not? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you push several images with the same tag, like `STG`, each new image will overwrite the already existing tag of the older image.
So at every time, you will have only one image with `STG` tag.

Now if you push one image tagged `base-old` and after that, you start pushing several `base-1`, `base-2`, ...., `base-n` you will actually use the Lifecycle policy with the prefix `base`.
Instead, if you push each time images with the same tag **base** you will not reach the count of images to actually use Lifecycle policy.